# How to RewriteRule with portnumber and urlmask

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect with portnumber and use a urlmask.

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.mysite\.com:([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://help\.mysite\.com:xxxx/$1 [L,NC,QSA,NE,P]
```

But I can't get it working, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match port and host separately:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^(\d+)$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^help\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:%1/$1 [L,NE,P]
```

Comment: help.mysite.com:xxxx gives service not available
help.mysite.com gives server time out

Comment: Same result. I am kind of blond here, just following your instructions. What exactly is the code doing?

Comment: Well you need to set your htaccess/config right first. I suspect you have other rules that are conflicting.

Comment: I forwarded the domain in a DNS record at the host. Don't need a mask now for the IP. Still the question remains of masking the Portnr. Seems to me not possible within my understanding.

Comment: Update your question will all the new details then I can check whether it is possible or not.